# MS Excel : COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

Tags: exception, excel-2007

I have not installed MS Office in my system.

I am getting the following error :

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154
Query:

Query here is do i need to install complete MS Office or Excel 2007 application.Due to license issue we can not install MS Office 2007.

or

Installation of any run time office redistributable will fix the above issue?

Comment: There is no "run time office redistributable", you have to pay money to get a license for Office.  The PIA is just glue to allow a .NET program to make Office COM calls, it doesn't implement Office.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use COM automation with Excel, Excel has to be installed on the machine. There is no "Office redistributable" that will allow you to avoid doing so.

If you need Excel's functionality, you either have to install Excel or purchase and install a third-party equivalent that will create Excel-compatible files.

Comment: So i can't simply nuget the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.excel` package  and use it's features without installing Excel on the user's machine?

Comment: @techno: No. You can't have interop with something that doesn't exist, and you can't automate Excel if it's not installed.